# Could Kamala Harris use “will” instead of “are going to” in this short viral video?

Tags: will-be-going

In [this short viral video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3lpFE19T78) on Youtube, Kamala Harris says:

> We did it. We did it, Joe. You're going to be the next president of
> the United States.

Could she use “will” instead of “are going to”?

Comment: Equally grammatical. Equally idiomatic. Same base meaning. But more of a congratulatory feel ... less clinical.

Comment: She doesn’t even need the word *going* there.

Comment: She's the vice-president-elect of the United States. She can say anything she wants to.

Comment: Who is Camilla Harris?

Comment: You’re thinking of C. Parder-Bowles, @David. Think other side of the pond.

Comment: @Xanne — I think I’ll duck that pond.

Comment: @David She is to Biden what Pence is to Trump. Given Biden's age she could easily end up being President.

Comment: @BoldBen — You surprise me. I thought the life expectancy of US presidents was about 110 years. Although I gather life expectancy overall has been falling in the US. Anyway, I would hope she would be judged ultimately by her actions rather than her words.

Comment: going to is spoken, colloquial English here. "will" would be more like a prediction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We did it. We did it, Joe. You're **going to be** the next president of the United States.

Using "going to" suggests something that is imminent, an event that is about to happen in the not too distant future. Harris based her prediction on *present* evidence; not on a hunch, theory, or hope but on fact: the number of Electoral College votes won by Biden's team.

Saying that, she could have easily said: “We did it. We did it, Joe. You'**ll be** the next president of the United States” and the meaning would not have changed.
Some grammar books explain that "will" is used for predictions, promises, facts and for instant decisions. The news of the victory means Joe Biden becoming the 46th President of the US is the *promised* or *factual* outcome i.e., Joe Biden **will enter** the White House on January 20, 2021.

> In keeping with tradition, the inauguration **will be held** on Wednesday January 20, in front of the US Capitol in Washington DC.
> (*The Telegraph*)

> Relax. Biden **will be sworn in** Jan. 20.
> President-elect Joe Biden **will be inaugurated** at noon on Jan. 20.
> (*The Washington Post*)

As the inauguration date gets nearer, native speakers will probably say, “Biden is going to be inaugurated on Wednesday”.

It worth pointing out that the contracted form “'ll” is far more natural in casual speech whereas the full form is preferable in formal speech and writing.

Answer (score 2):

Both could have been used by Kamala Harris, but, "be going to" sounds more appropriate here.

"be going to" is about an action in a more or less near future. It is about something which has been planned. What's more, "be going to" sounds more enthusiastic, more energetic.

"will" is about the future as well, but it can be a distant or a near future. "will" adds the idea of willingness, of determination, something that you really want (!) to do.

Comment: In Binnick's original article (Binnick, Robert I. 1971. “Will and Be Going To,” CLS 7, 40–52), he gives the example of a shout to a climbing companion: _Watch out! That rock is going to fall!_, as opposed to the very strange ?*_Watch out! That rock will fall!_ The generalization is that _going to_ (universally pronounced _gonna_) is for imminent events, whereas _will_ is a modal and has multiple senses like any modal.

Answer (score 1):

Both can be used, as shown here: https://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Future_Will_vs_Going.htm.

Going to is used when something has shown definite signs of happening.

Example: It is going to rain this evening.

And can also be used when you are definitely intending to do something.

Example: I am going to go to the park this evening.

Also when something is about to happen: His bag is going to rip, it's so full of books!

Will is used when you are predicting something.

Example: It will rain this evening.

And for rapid decisions:

I will go to the park this evening (I've just decided to go to the park)

And for making offers, threats, etc:

I'll give you the mango for two (currency)s today. It's a discount.

Answer (score -1):

When you're talking about actions that are far into the future (months or maybe years from now), you can have use "will". When you're talking about actions that you will do soon (tomorrow or next week), you can use "going to". So, in this case in is correct to say the word "will" instead of "are going to".